# problem of transmitting data from serial device to bluetooth on Arduino

Tags: arduino, i2c, bluetooth, uart

I am using an accelerometer which uses serial communication on Arduino (UART), I wish to transmit the data to a bluetooth module (blusmirf gold) using I2C and finally read it from my android application.

I am able to detect the correct reading from accelerometer, I am also able to transmit the data through bluetooth. However, when i put these two things together, it only transmit once and stop transmitting anything afterwards.

Is there anyone can help me with this? Thanks in advance!

```
/*Hardware hookup:
  Arduino --------------- MMA8452Q Breakout
    3.3V  ---------------     3.3V
    GND   ---------------     GND
  SDA (A4) --\/330 Ohm\/--    SDA
  SCL (A5) --\/330 Ohm\/--    SCL
*/
#include <Wire.h> // Must include Wire library for I2C
#include <SFE_MMA8452Q.h> // Includes the SFE_MMA8452Q library
#include <Event.h>
#include <Timer.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#include <SoftwareSerial.h>  
int bluetoothTx = 16;  // TX-O pin of bluetooth mate, Arduino A2,16
int bluetoothRx = 17;  // RX-I pin of bluetooth mate, Arduino A3,17
MMA8452Q accel;
SoftwareSerial bluetooth(bluetoothTx, bluetoothRx); // for communication between ATMEGA 328 and BlueSMiRF Gold

int Start_But =4;
int LED_init =7;
int LED_start =8;

int x[20];
int y[20];
int sum=0;
int sum1=0;
float begin_val1;
float begin_val2;
int type;
int start_ref1;
int start_ref2;
float start_point ;
float force_sum;
float force_value1 ;
float force_value2;
float voltage_value ;
char value[10];
char value2[10];

// taking the sensor reading and convert it to the force value and transmit  


void setup()
{
delay(300);
   Serial.begin(9600);  // Begin the serial monitor at 57600bps

Serial.println("lalalalalalalalalaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");

  // bluetooth.println("MMA8452Q Test Code!");
delay(200);
Wire.begin();
delay(100);
Serial.println("lalalalalalalalalsssssss");

accel.init();
Serial.println("lalalal");
//delay(2000);
bluetooth.begin(9600);  // The Bluetooth Mate defaults to 115200bps
pinMode(Start_But,INPUT);
pinMode(LED_start,OUTPUT);
pinMode(LED_init,OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(LED_init,1);
digitalWrite(LED_start,0);
analogReference(INTERNAL);//set the analog output reference to be 3.3V instead of 5V since the output voltage from the sensors are small
 
//Taking the several readings under no load condition to decide which relationship between voltage and force the sensor is following 
 x[0]=analogRead(1);
  delay(100);
    x[1]=analogRead(1);
  delay(100);
  sum+=x[1];
    x[2]=analogRead(1);
    delay(100);
  sum+=x[2];
    x[3]=analogRead(1);
  delay(100);
  sum+=x[3];
    x[4]=analogRead(1);
   delay(100);
  sum+=x[4];
    x[5]=analogRead(1);
  delay(100);
  sum+=x[5];
    x[6]=analogRead(1);
   delay(100);
  sum+=x[6];
    x[7]=analogRead(1);
  delay(100);
  sum+=x[7]; 
  x[8]=analogRead(1);
  delay(100);
  sum+=x[8];
    x[9]=analogRead(1);
  delay(100);
  sum+=x[9];
    x[10]=analogRead(1);
  delay(100);
  sum+=x[10];
begin_val1=sum/10;
y[0]=analogRead(0);
  delay(100);
    y[1]=analogRead(0);
  delay(100);
  sum1+=y[1];
    y[2]=analogRead(0);
    delay(100);
  sum1+=y[2];
    y[3]=analogRead(0);
  delay(100);
  sum1+=x[3];
    y[4]=analogRead(0);
   delay(100);
  sum1+=x[4];
    y[5]=analogRead(0);
  delay(100);
  sum1+=x[5];
    y[6]=analogRead(0);
   delay(100);
  sum1+=x[6];
    y[7]=analogRead(0);
  delay(100);
  sum1+=x[7]; 
  y[8]=analogRead(0);
  delay(100);
  sum1+=x[8];
    y[9]=analogRead(0);
  delay(100);
  sum1+=x[9];
    y[10]=analogRead(0);
  delay(100);
  sum1+=x[10];
begin_val2=sum1/10;

 digitalWrite(LED_init,0);
  digitalWrite(LED_start,1);
Serial.println("lalalalalalalalal");
  
}

void loop()
{
  while(1)
  {
  Serial.println ("oi");
   accel.read();
   Serial.println("aa");
//  
 int xAcceleration = accel.cx*100; 
 int yAcceleration = accel.cy*100; 
int total =xAcceleration+yAcceleration;
Serial.print("ACC");
Serial.println(total);
//bluetooth.print("ACCB");
//bluetooth.println(total);
//delay(15);

   int start_ref1=(analogRead(1));
  int start_ref2=(analogRead(0));
     force_value1=(start_ref1-begin_val1)/25;
 if(force_value1<=0)
   {
     force_value1=0.0;
   }
   if(force_value1>=25)
   {
     force_value1=force_value1*0.8;
   }
   force_value2=(start_ref2-begin_val2)/5;
    if(force_value2<=0)
   {
     force_value2=0.0;
   }
  if(force_value2>=25)
   {
     force_value2=force_value2*0.8;
   }
force_sum=(force_value1+force_value2)*0.8;

dtostrf(force_sum,3,2,value);
String str(value);
str="N"+str;
delay(20);
//Serial.print("force");
//Serial.println(str);
bluetooth.print("FORCEB");
 bluetooth.println(str);
 delay(500);





  } 

}
```

Comment: The problem is a missing semicolon on line 42

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add the code you're using, please? Without it, it will be impossible to know what the problem is.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! the code has been added! can anyone find the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a mistake in your firmware (program). What I mean is that you run through the "Send whatever to bluetooth module" once and then not again.

It should look something like this in your program:

```
while(1) // Forever and ever since 1 won't change. 
{

Read whatever from accelorometer();
return xy;

Transmit to bluetooth(xy);

}
```

Comment: Hi bummi, Thanks for your reply! I have uploaded the code, can you kindly help me to check again? Thanks so much!

Comment: Transmit to bluetooth(xy);  will be never executed after return.